# Empty $err document on query failure

Tags: mongodb, error-handling, protocols

Is it possible in Mongo DB wire protocol that QueryFailure is set, but response doesn't have $err field set or $err is empty?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I believe ideally that will not be the case. Do you have any specific instance when it happens?